# Multiple criteria from multiple columns CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a database for cattle and when they meet 3 criteria they are considered "Prime", I want to add a column which states whether the animal is prime after checking against the three criteria:

- `ColdWeight >= 100`
- `MonthsAtSlaughter <=30`
- `AnimalTypeCode in ('A','C','E')`

I looked up "if" (I am really excel based and new to SQL) and found I should use Case, I have used it once before but only for one criteria, this is multiple criteria with different levels within criteria

```
case when ColdWeight >= 100
    and MonthsAtSlaughter <=30
    and AnimalTypeCode in ('A','C','E')
        then '1'
        else '0' As Prime
```

I'm getting the below error,

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'case'.

Comment: You are missing `END` : `case when ColdWeight >= 100
    and MonthsAtSlaughter <=30
    and AnimalTypeCode in ('A','C','E')
        then '1'
        else '0' END As Prime`

Comment: `End` is missing, but the error is probably caused by a missing comma before the CASE

Comment: Please show us the **complete** `SELECT` statement.

Comment: END is missing.  update the end part as follows -- `else '0' END As Prime`

Comment: Thanks, everyone- it was the missing comma and missing ```end```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a complete query and `end`:

```
select (case when ColdWeight >= 100 and
                  MonthsAtSlaughter <= 30 and
                  AnimalTypeCode in ('A', 'C', 'E')
             then '1'
             else '0'
        end) As Prime
from t;
```